# JQuery Slide Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the code in example http://www.faridesign.net/2012/05/create-a-awesome-vertical-tabbed-content-area-using-css3-jquery/ I am trying to slide the div tags on a button click on the list so the current tab-content will slide in and the tab just clicked will slide out. I currently have the working example where I can switch between divs fine, but I need to slide in and out between divs. Is there any script I can do this with the current code. using .slide or .effect instead of .show() looks to display two divs at the same time. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<div id="v-nav">
<ul>
    <li tab="tab1" class="first current">Main Screen</li>
    <li tab="tab2">Div 1</li>
    <li tab="tab3">Div 2</li>
    <li tab="tab4">Div 3</li>
    <li tab="tab5">Div 4</li>
    <li tab="tab6">Div 5</li>
    <li tab="tab7">Div 6</li>
    <li tab="tab8" class="last">Div 7</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <h4>Main Screen</h4>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 1</h4>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 2</h4>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 3</h4>    
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 4</h4>                   
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 5</h4>                   
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 6</h4>                   
</div>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Div 7</h4>  
</div>
```

My Script looks like

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
        items.removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        //hide all content divs and show current one
        //$('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show();

        //$('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).fadeIn(100);    

        $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).slideToggle();
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
    });
});

if (location.hash) {
    showTab(location.hash);
}
else {
    showTab("tab1");
}

function showTab(tab) {
    $("#v-nav ul li:[tab*=" + tab + "]").click();
}

// Bind the event hashchange, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
$(window).hashchange(function () {
    showTab(location.hash.replace("#", ""));
})

// Trigger the event hashchange on page load, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
$(window).hashchange();

});
```

Comment: Could you show your css please? Also, putting $(this).click inside of a $('selector').each seems weird when you could just do $('selector').click.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Vertical jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical). You might have to restyle a little bit, but I think the effect is what you want. You should be able to add the slide effect from http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/ to the change tab event.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do this with a Click function. I want to avoid using .tabs()

Comment: Actually replace .show() with .toggle("slide") works well but I need to slide in the opposite direction. toggle does not look to have a direction parameter.

Comment: I think you can just add the opts dictionary after the "slide": `$( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide", {direction: "right"} );`

Comment: In order to use the direction parameter I need to add the jquery-ui js file. Once I add this the toggle does not work as well. It only slides in the content and once the content has completed will the background of the div appear. Not nice :(

Comment: You're going to have to slide in the new pane as well in the same script. Is that what you mean? It's getting difficult to know what you mean by "does not work as well".